# convert a string array to array in php

Tags: php, arrays

so like this

I have an array that is stored in the database, so the array must first be converted into a string. so how to return the array that I changed into the form of a string?

this the array i have, with var_dump and xdebug

```php
barang.php:59:string '["warna" => ["merah","hitam","navy"], "ukuran" => ["40","41","42","43", "44"]]' (length=78)
```

seen that it is a string. but the formatting inside is an array.

thanks

Comment: Just for clarification, is the type within the database an array, or is it a SET, JSON, or a string that looks like an array?

Comment: maybe a string that looks like an array . . .

Comment: You have a suboptimal condition. Whenever you convert something of any complexity “to string”, it is your burden to handle the reverse case using an inversion of your original logic. PHP has an official way to do this through serialization, but that’s not what I’m seeing. How was this “array as string” originally created? I’d start there

Comment: What is your original input string? That looks like an array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'd suggest cleaning up your database and saving the data in a better format. I'd suggest either serializing it with `json_encode` or `serialize` or normalizing the data into separate rows and writing custom code to read it out of the database.

But if you must work with this as is, you can get away with `eval` here:

```
<?php

$string = '["warna" => ["merah","hitam","navy"], "ukuran" => ["40","41","42","43", "44"]]';

eval('$foo = ' . $string . ' ;');

var_dump($foo);
```

outputs:

```
array(2) {
  ["warna"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "merah"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "hitam"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "navy"
  }
  ["ukuran"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(2) "40"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "41"
    [2]=>
    string(2) "42"
    [3]=>
    string(2) "43"
    [4]=>
    string(2) "44"
  }
}
```

[Example here on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/W7ufD)

Be mindful that using `eval` is risky and be absolutely certain the data you're using it on is precisely what you think it is.

Comment: Using `eval` is sooo evil that I wouldn't even think of using it. 

Stick to the `json_decode` solution or anything else